# Why can't I use a counter in recursion?

Tags: python

I want to know why this code won't run. I am trying to code a Fibonacci sequence using recursion.

```
def fib(z):
    counter = 1
    nTwo    = 0
    nOne    = 1
    n       = nTwo + nOne

    if counter == z:
        return n

    else:
        counter = 1 + counter
        fib(counter)
        counter += 1
        nTwo    = nOne
        nOne    = n
        n       = nTwo + nOne
        fib(z)

z = 10
fib(z)
```

Why does this not work?

I want to know what is wrong with the 'logic' behind it.

Comment: I strongly advise you to read [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it would help you in making your code much cleaner and esy to understand.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: `counter` will be always `1`.

Comment: There's just too many things wrong here to fix each of them individually – you'll find literally hundreds of examples of recursive Fibonacci functions in Python with a simple Google search. I suggest you study one of them instead and start over.

Comment: Every function call has its own local variables. Every call to `fib` uses its own `counter` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys.

vishes_shell I will do
jonrshape Thanks for the link, but my code won't even run on it haha!
@NiklasR is there a reason why that is?

Comment: @melpomene I see, but I still get the error when I make counter global. Should that not add to the counter?

Comment: What error? You never said anything about an error.

Comment: @melpomene 

 RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an example of how to do the Fibonacci sequence in Python recursively, here is something:

```
def fib(z)
    if z == 0:
         return 0
    if z == 1:
         return 1
    return fib(z-1) + fib(z-2)
```

When you call fib(z), it only knows of the variable 'z', the 'counter' variable of one function call is independent from another function call (you could do fib(z, counter), but that's unnecessary.

Answer (score -3):

It's more simple using `while`, and using 3 variables.
EXAMPLE:

```
while True:
    num0=1
    num1=num0 + num0
    num2=num1+num0
    while num0 > num1:
        num1 += num2
        num2 += num1
```

Comment: OP is explicitly asking about a recursive version.

Comment: It also looks like an infinite loop to me.

Comment: `num0 > num1` is never true.